# Why does the proportions_ztest function in statsmodels produce different values than the formula for a 1-proportion Z test?

Tags: python, z-test, statsmodels

If I run the following code in Python:

```py
from statsmodels.stats.proportion import proportions_ztest
proportions_ztest(10, 50, 0.5)
```

the result is `(-5.303300858899106, 1.1372725656979709e-07)`

However, if I use the formula for a 1-proportion Z test (taken from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/statistics/one_proportion_z_test.htm)):

```py
import math
import scipy.stats

def my_ztest(successes, n, p_0):
    p_hat = successes / n
    z = (p_hat - p_0) / math.sqrt(p_0 * (1 - p_0) / n)
    p = scipy.stats.norm.sf(abs(z)) * 2
    return z, p

my_ztest(10, 50, 0.5)
```

Both the z-score and the p-value are different: `(-4.242640687119285, 2.2090496998585445e-05)`

Why does the statsmodels function produce a different value than what is defined by the formula?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`proportions_ztest` seems to work exactly as documented.

Unfortunately what the documentation says it does is just not what you're expecting it to do.

By default this function uses the *sample* proportion in calculating the standard error of $p-p_0$. There's an option (via a boolean function argument) to change that default, after which the output should match your own calculation.

I feel the writers of the documentation have let you down: The documentation doesn't make this arguably nonstandard default sufficiently obvious to the naive reader - in fact, it's pretty hard to spot (I found it fairly easily only because I *knew to expect something like this*).

[The choice itself is reasonable, but failing to make it blatantly clear - e.g. with a warning in bold lettering right at the top of the documentation - amounts to *user-vicious* behaviour. You don't put such a big "gotcha" into your packages without *really* good reason, and you make sure people can easily tell when you do.]

Edit: This question has led to a ticket relating to the documentation (see comments below). I applaud the fast action taken -- though the documentation itself may not rapidly change, something productive happened. I am not used to my complaints about documentation (I've made a ton of them here, about various programs) being acted on at all.

Comment: Why is the score test more "standard" than the Wald test. AFAIR, I have seen both very frequently either emphasizing one or the other. (Wald tests are more common even in cases where score tests have better properties, i.e. maintain size better than Wald tests.) (The score test for two sample comparison with nonzero difference requires constrained optimization.)

Comment: *Usage*. I estimate that easily ten times as many people learn and use the test the OP did. Take the most popular *intro* stats texts across a wide variety of application areas. Now count the number of people who do courses using these books and compare with the number who learn the Wald test first. *That's* the audience for basic tests (more sophisticated audiences can easily code their own). Those are also typically the people least likely to be able to guess what might have been done instead.  If you're implementing a Wald test, call it that, right in the function name.

Comment: R https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/prop.test doesn't specify which probabilites they use for the variance. IIRC, I used SAS documentation when I wrote that function. https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_freq_a0000000563.htm

Comment: If this was a question about the corresponding R function or its documentation, I would likely have been critical of it (I have been before). I see nothing in what you said that would a good reason not to explain exactly what the statistic is in the documentation (I didn't say the choice of statistic was wrong, in fact I said it was reasonable, and it is, the problem is with how it was ***documented***), and I also see nothing that would be a good reason not to *very clearly* indicate what to do to achieve other statistics beginners might reasonably want to use in the documentation.

Comment: It would have required *less* effort to amend the documentation of the function to be vastly more helpful to beginners than it did to write all of the above comments. The mere appearance of the question should have been motivation enough to do something about it.

Comment: It was motivation enough to open an issue https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/6488 But most likely this old function will get a larger make-over, maybe splitting out the two sample case. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/4829/files#diff-36a55e208f6d1db357321ee87ef3ab77R1399

Comment: thanks for the comments

Comment: Thanks. I should mention that the test the OP was implementing for comparison was not the score test, but rather a direct normal approximation to the binomial test; that's what most intro books will discuss (when they motivate what they're doing at all).

Comment: A convenient example of this would be Zar, *Biostatistical Analysis*, 5E, p568-70 (the nearest book to hand that explicitly explains the justification for the usual one sample proportions test typically seen in intro books across a variety of application areas).

Answer (score 2):

Even though @Glen_b answer is completely right, it doesn't mention the parameter they are referring to.

For others who may fall into this same problem, the right way of using `proportions_ztest` the way the OP tried to use it is as follows:

```
from statsmodels.stats.proportion import proportions_ztest
proportions_ztest(10, 50, 0.5, prop_var=0.5)
```

so that the actual calculation is (with $p_0$ as the null hypothesis):

$
\begin{equation}
p_1 = \frac{successes}{n}\\
Z = \cfrac{p_1-p_0}{\sqrt{\frac{p_0(1-p_0)}{n}}} \\
\end{equation}
$

**On the other hand**:

if not setting `prop_var` with the **same** value as $p_0$, then `statsmodels` calculates $Z$ in a different way:

$Z = \cfrac{p_1-p_0}{\sqrt{\frac{p_1(1-p_1)}{n}}}$

Why that? Because when `prop_var` is not set, the standard error is estimated using the samples provided, which are always the first two parameters of `proportions_ztests`, be them two values or two lists of values (as used when calculating the test for two proportions).